# Not seeing Google Analytics reports after being added as user

Tags: google-analytics

I've been using Google Analytics for a while under my personal account.

My employer recently added me as a user (administrator) for their GA reports, using the above account (Gmail address).

However, I see no mention of those new reports on my GA home page. Is there another step that needs to be done for me to see those reports?

Comment: It should just work - I have similar access from my employer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I've found that I go straight into one account on Google Analytics, which has a few sites on it. However there is an Accounts menu at the top right that allows you to switch between them - have you checked whether the other account is listed up in that box?

Comment: Or on the page listing your profiles, look for breadcrumb links and click on 'Overview'.